# Is there a Capability that checks as true for non-logged in users?

Tags: user-roles

Wondering if I can do a `current_user_can` check to see if the user is not logged in.

I specifically need to check again `current_user_can`, so `is_user_logged_in` won't work in this case.

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? And why does is_user_logged_in won´t work?

Answer (score 2):

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
 // your code for logged in user 
} else {
 // your code for logged out user 
}
```

or perhaps...

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
```

...specifically:

```
<?php
 $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
 if ( 0 == $current_user->ID ) {
  // Not logged in.
 } else {
  // Logged in.
 }
?>
```

...might lead the way?

Comment: If this helped Nathan you can mark it as the answer, thanks